# how to set a random border color for each element inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on code to tag images. I was able to insert the tags and for each inserted tag a small box is created and tagname will be displayed inside. What I would like to do is, to have different color for each of the box created

css:

```
.inputtag>i {
    margin-right: 4px;
    } 
.inputtag {
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid skyblue;
        color: #000;
        padding: 2px 8px;
        width: max-content;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 4px 4px;
        float: left;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
   var html = "<div class='inputtag'><i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'></i><i class='fa fa-trash-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i><span>" + input + "</span><input type='hidden' name='tag_name[]' value='" + input + "'></div>";
   $('.tags').append(html);
```

Below i have attached the image for my question:

[image]

If you see the image , you can see both the box have the same border color(skyblue). I would like to have different colors for each of these boxes.

Can someone guide me how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give them all same class name then u can use `querSelectorAll` to find them
and then with `forEach` method assign randomly generated color;

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach(el => el.style.borderColor ="#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16));
```

```css
.test{
   border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use different class for individual boxes and assign different colours in css.